# Do you need to explicitly include headers that other headers already include themselves?

Tags: c++, header, include

Given a header file `foo.h`:

```cpp
#include <bar>

// ...
```

And a file `baz.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

// ...
```

Do you need to explicitly include the `bar` header into `baz.cpp` in order to use it? Or can you just start using it since it's included in `foo.h`?

Comment: If you use sth from `algorithm` directly in `main.cpp`, then yes; otherwise not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `#include <algorithm>` to `main.cpp` if `main.cpp` uses any functions or classes, or anything else that's defined in `<algorithm>`.

What some other translation unit uses is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to. Think of an "#include" as a direction to copy and paste the entire contents of the included file at that line.

other.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string getString()
{
    return "A String";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "other.h"


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec{getString(), getString()};

    for (auto &it : vec) {
        std::cout << it << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```